# Best method to allow user to choose multiple things from my DB?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

So I have a "Bars" table in my database and a "Add a Bar" form which allows a bar owner or manager to add his/her business listing to my website database. I also have a "Beers" table in my database and I want the owner/manager of the bar, when entering his/her bar info, to be able to pick how ever many beers from my database that they serve at the business.

I originally was thinking a drop-down menu but that's no good because that will only allow them to pick one. What if they want to add 20? Do you have any code suggestions for me? I don't even know what this is called, but I think it would be useful to have a drop-down and then a regular list and as they select beers from the drop-down, the regular list gets populated and then eventually all of the beers they chose are saved into the database and associated with the bar. However, I am not sure if this is the best implementation. Thank you.

Comment: That's most likely off topic since about usability design and not software architecture. Also which kind of user interface is 'best' is often enough just a matter of opinion. You could just have a single list of all beers and a checkbox to select those that are served. Or two lists and allow to drag&drop items. Also this seems a bit limiting. What will you do if they serve beer not on the list?

Comment: This might be a better fit for UX.SE

Comment: @GregBurghardt when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat: Is there any way to move this question?